# Laptop falls asleep too early

Tags: laptop, power

I'm using Dell Inspiron14z laptop.
My current power plan
dims the display/ turns off the display/ puts the computer to sleep
after 15/30/60 minutes on battery
and 30/60/120 minutes when plugged in.
But it actually turns off the display within 2~5 minutes.
Why does it act differently from the setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your task bar right click on the battery icon and then click on "Power Options" in the menu, a Control Panel window should open click on the "Change plan settings" next to your current power plan (The one with the filled in dot next to it), then click "Change advanced power settings", A window titled "Power Options" should appear. Scroll down until you get to the "Display" option expand it then "Turn off display after" and adjust the settings to your liking!

I hope this was what you were looking for!

Daniel

Comment: I can adjust those times in the 'Power Options' menu even without going to 'advanced power settings'. But it does not work as the setting; that's the reason I ask a question here.

Comment: @user67275 Oh right so you did haha... The only other thing I can think of is your screen saver settings in Personalization by right clicking on your Desktop.